# Language selector from selection option to a href tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a language selector that is working well with select - options. However, I want to change this to a/li tags instead. Could this work? Local storage is also being used within this, to take the users options.

```js
$('[lang="fr"]').hide();
$('[lang="sp"]').hide();

let savedLang = "en"
//let savedLang = localStorage.getItem('lang')

if (savedLang) {
  let element = document.querySelector(`option[value='${savedLang}']`);
  element.selected = true
  selectText(savedLang);
}

$('#lang-switch').change(function() {
  var lang = $(this).val();
  //Local storage wont work at Stack Overflow
  //localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
  selectText(lang);
})

function selectText(lang) {
  switch (lang) {
    case 'en':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="en"]').show();
      break;
    case 'fr':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="fr"]').show();
      break;
    case 'sp':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="sp"]').show();
      break;
    default:
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="en"]').show();
  }
}
```

```css
[lang="fr"],
[lang="sp"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Change language</p>

<select id="lang-switch">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="sp">Spanish</option>
</select>

<p lang="en">Hello!</p>
<p lang="fr">Bojour!</p>
<p lang="sp">Hola!</p>
```

Comment: Yes it can still work. Do you have a specific issue with it?

Comment: Li's are much more simpler to style! :)

Comment: I think what Rory means is, did you try it before asking? And if so, are you having a problem with it? It would seem the answer to your question is just simply "yes" :).

Comment: I tried changing option value to a data-value, but no luck

Comment: Hm, I think I've misunderstood. I thought you wanted to replace the `<p>` tags with `<a>` or `<li>`, not the `<select>`. In that case, can you share your attempt so we can help you debug, as opposed to the part that's already working? Thanks Brad.

Comment: Hi Tyler, I created this with options. Im now however a little stuck on how to change the options to li's. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How can I target via li?

Comment: Wheres the problem you are having? Is it replacing the `select` via a dropdown made out of `<li>`'s or is it getting the event change of the <li>?